# Why this code is giving one output as there are two arugents?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Foo:
    def printLine(self, line='Python'):
        print(line)

o1 = Foo()
o1.printLine('Java')
```

why is it giving one output??

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is only one arguments in the printLine function. And, 'Java' override the 'Python'.